# Extrude the faces near my selection

Tags: node-editor, geometry, extrude

I have made a good selection in geometry nodes that I'm happy with:

[image]

I feed it into the extrude node, and I can extrude the vertices and edges using that selection correctly, but when I try it with faces it wont acknowledge the selection, does anyone know why? Thanks for the reading!

[image]

[image]

[image: How the selection is made]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't even show us how you did the face selection. thx.

Comment: Does it necessarily matter? The selection if based off of normals, and comparing with equals and adding them together, I will include it in the question now^^

Comment: tbh your selection makes not that much sense to me. can u tell us how you want to select it and why? so maybe tell us your end goal? or do you just want to select "inner faces" of a cube? so e.g. to select the "inner" faces you could do this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTx30.png

Comment: That was more or less what I was trying yes, turns out my selection still works but I needed the 'Evaluate on Domain' node after the selection set to 'points', so thanks for the tip :)

Comment: glad it worked for u